# Fix tableheader from tableview in 0,0,320,45?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios5

I'm adding table header just like this in tableview:

```
TableHeaderView *tableHeaderView  = [[TableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
tableview.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView;
```

So when i scroll to top i want table header stopped in position it was initialized (0,0). When i scroll down, it goes from screen, exactly instagram tableheader does. take a look to table header instagram its what i want to do..

When initialize the app.

[image]

When scrolls to top, table header stay in your initilize position

[image]

When scroll down, if tableheader is in you current position, it going out of screen
[image]

[image]

Remember when scroll top tableheader need to appear depending scroll position

Comment: It's not clear yet, Please elaborate.

Comment: @rptwsthi take a look again...

Comment: If you want the table header view to be be in a fixed position, you should add it as subview of your view controller and not as `tableHeaderView`

Comment: @CainaSouza so how to start hiding when scroll to down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question a bit not correct. Actually you want to scroll away UINavigationBar. Try this solution, it may be useful for you:

http://horseshoe7.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/uinavigationbar-that-scrolls-away/

Comment: already tested..nice, i didn't know much about layers, but now i know its very important and useful ! ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

as I see on screenshot - it's not a table header (self.tableView.tableHeaderView) - it's section header, isn't it?

Comment: registers are sections, but the top menu Instagram that has an update button, i its a table header i think

Comment: do you mean a blue line with title "Instagram" and update UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: oh think I got what you mean now! let me think